# ERROR in Cannot read property 'loadChildren' of undefined when tried to set the path

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, ionic4

I need to conditionally load the route path. I have tried below. But it gives this error. Can you tell me how to do this kind of task?

> [ng] ERROR in Cannot read property 'loadChildren' of undefined [ng] i
>   ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

And:

> app-routing.module.ts:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'getLandingPage' of undefined
>       at Module../src/app/app-routing.module.ts (app-routing.module.ts:21)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:83)
>       at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:21)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:83)
>       at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:1)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:83)
>       at Object.0 (main.ts:13)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:83)
>       at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
>       at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)

*app.routing.module.ts*

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    redirectTo: this.getLandingPage(), // here is the issue
    pathMatch: "full",
  },
  {
   path: "tabs",
   loadChildren: "./pages/tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule",
  },
  {
   path: 'landing',
  loadChildren: './pages/landing/landing.module#LandingPageModule'
 },
];

export class AppRoutingModule {

  getLandingPage(): string {
    let url = "";
    switch (environment.hotelName) {
      case "h1":
        url = "tabs";
        break;
      case "h2":
        url = "landing";
        break;
      default:
    }
    return url;
  }


}
```

I have `auth.gurad.ts` as shown below. I don't think where I can use it for this.

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router,
    private user: UserService,
    private localStorageService: LocalStorageService) { }
  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise(async resolve => {
      const userInfo: UserInfo = await this.localStorageService.get(LocalStorage.USER_INFO);
      if (userInfo && (moment() < moment(userInfo.expireDate))) {
        this.user.guest = false;
        return resolve(true);
      }
      this.user.guest = true;
      this.router.navigate(["/sign-in"]);
      return resolve(false);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: and where is the definition for tabs / landing?

Comment: @jcuypers Updated. Please see it.

Comment: you would need to add / prefix to the url in your getLandingpage

Comment: can you also copy and paste the definition for "/pages/" ?  Can you confirm the goal is to lazy load?

Comment: @jcuypers Yes, this is lazy loaded pages.

Comment: Is it possible to just make a simple stackblitz bcs its difficult to see if all parts are there.  just the basic features for lazy loading will do

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to what a lot of other people have experienced with rouge commas.  Remove the last comma at the end of your route list, since the router thinks that there are 4 items, the last being a `void 0`/`undefined` item, and thus missing the `loadChildren`.

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    redirectTo: getLandingPage(),
    pathMatch: "full",
  },
  {
    path: "tabs",
    loadChildren: "./pages/tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule",
  },
  {
    path: 'landing',
    loadChildren: './pages/landing/landing.module#LandingPageModule'
  }
];
```

*(notice the missing comma after your 'landing' route entry)*

Answer (score 2):

### Check for any programmatic logic in your router config

*This problem might occur when you use something else then a simple object with string keys and string values inside your router configuration.*

---

In my case it occurred when setting a regular expression inside the data object of a certain route:

```
{
  path: 'path', 
  component: MyComponent,
  data: {
    regEx: /^[a-f\d]{24}$/i,
  },
},
```

The compiler choked on this and simply reported the non-descriptive error:

> ERROR in Cannot read property 'loadChildren' of undefined

---

Other examples I found on people running into this issue are related. For example [this one on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4686#issuecomment-400572965) where someone uses a constant for a key of a resolver:

```
const SOME_CONSTANT = 'someResolver',

{
  path: 'path',
  component: MyComponent,
  resolve: {
    [SOME_CONSTANT]: SomeResolver, // <-- you can't do this
  },
},
```

In other words, when running into this issue check if you have some keys, values or other parts of your router config defined programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Route Guards, why not just use a guard in the full match, and do the redirect from there? use conditionals where needed

Example:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    canActivate: [RouteGuard]
 },
  {
   path: "tabs",
   loadChildren: "./pages/tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule",
  },
  {
   path: 'landing',
  loadChildren: './pages/landing/landing.module#LandingPageModule'
 },
];
```

RouteGuard:

```
 canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise(async resolve => {
        this.router.navigate([environment.hotelName]);
        resolve(true)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be defining `getLandingPage()` outside of your `AppRoutingModule`:

```
const getLandingPage = (): string => {
    let url = "";
    switch (hotelName) {
      case "h1":
        url = "tabs";
        break;
      case "h2":
        url = "landing";
        break;
      default:
    }
    return url;
  };

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    redirectTo: getLandingPage(),
    pathMatch: "full",
  },
  {
    path: "tabs",
    loadChildren: "./pages/tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule",
  },
  {
    path: 'landing',
    loadChildren: './pages/landing/landing.module#LandingPageModule'
  },
];
```

Stackblitz example (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-lazy-loading-hroo3l?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts) Uses const `hotelName` instead of environment, since stackblitz doesn't have environment variable defined.

Also not sure how nicely it will play with AOT.

Answer (score 0):

I get this same error today '**ERROR in Cannot read property 'loadChildren' of undefined**'.

I think this error could occurs in many ways. But for me, it was just a missing 'export' on a CanActivate class.

I had :

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
class MyActivator implements CanActivate
```

In fact I should have :

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class MyActivator implements CanActivate
```

This error was a little bit tricky to find ! So I just want to mention it here.